# Unable to send and receive images between 2 Raspberry connected to Zigbee via UART

Tags: qt, uart, zigbee

I have 2 Raspberry Pi4 connected to Zigbee via UART, I wrote the program to receive and send between the two devices. My program can send and receive character data very accurately, but when I send data from a photo, the program never receives enough data. I tried a PC connected to Zigbee and sent pictures to Pi via RealTerm, on Pi I received photos. What is the problem here? Or does anyone have another way to send photos between 2 Raspberry connected to Zigbee via UART? Thanks very much.

**Program send:**

```
#include "ui_serial.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QFile>


serial::serial(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::serial)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
    serialPort->setPortName("ttyAMA0");
    serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    if (serialPort->isOpen() == true){
        qDebug() <<"Port Opened....";
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(on_readdata()));
    }
}
void serial::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QFile* imageFile = new QFile("/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg");
        imageFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QByteArray ba = imageFile->readAll();
        imageFile->close();
        delete imageFile;
        if(serialPort->isOpen()==true){
            serialPort->write(ba);
            qDebug()<<ba.size()<<"size_send:";
        }
}
```

**Program read:**

```
#include "ui_serial.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>

serial::serial(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::serial)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
    serialPort->setPortName("ttyAMA0");
    serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    if (serialPort->isOpen() == true){
        qDebug() <<"Port Opened....";
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(on_readdata()));
    }
}

void serial::on_readdata()
{
    QByteArray ba;
    while (serialPort->waitForReadyRead(1000)){
        ba.append(serialPort->readAll());
    }
    qDebug()<<ba.size()<<"sizeeeee:";
    QFile newDoc("/home/pi/Desktop/imagexx.jpg");
            if(newDoc.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
                newDoc.write(ba);
            }
            newDoc.close();
}
```

Comment: Consider using signals and slots to handle the communication instead of the blocking approach with `waitForReadyRead(1000)`.

Comment: Further to the comment above, your code has a number of issues.  Firstly you never check the value returned by `serialPort->write(ba)` -- I don't think there's any guarantee that all data is written.  More importantly, however, you never let the receiver know how much data to expect.  You might want to consider using a [`QDataStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) to aid (de)serialization.

Comment: @scopchanov Thank you for replying, I am thinking of replacing `waitForReadyRead(1000)` with `while (! Port-> atEnd ())`, is that a good way?

Comment: This is the exact same aproach. To help you further, I should ask: do you know the difference between polling and interrupt?

Comment: @G.M. Thank you for replying, i will consider it.

Comment: @scopchanov I know about it.

Comment: So, you have already subscribed for / connected to this interrupt / event / signal - _readyreadyRead_. There is no need to poll the data with `waitForReadyRead(1000)`. Just use `serialPort->readAll()` and you are good to go.

Comment: @scopchanov I tried, but they all gave the same result.I checked with 5kB image, in both ways, and they received 145 bytes, all the time. Having problems with the send data program?

Comment: Data might be sent in small portions. `qDebug` the result of `serialPort->readAll()` and you will see what is comming.

Comment: @scopchanov Yes, I used qDebug and it received 145 bytes, always 145 bytes. I tried sending another file, it also received a different value, but that value was always fixed.

Comment: Did you try this on a computer with a loop-back?

Comment: @scopchanov Here are the cases I have tried:
1. I have tried my program on 2 pi4 connected directly to each other via UART (not via Zigbee) to send pictures, it works fine.
2. Tried sending photos from PC to PI via Zigbee, it also works fine.
3. Send character string between 2 PIs through Zigbee, it also works fine.
4. Send photos between 2 Pi through Zigbee, it does not receive enough data.
5. Send photos from Pi to PC via Zigbee, it also doesn't receive enough data.

Comment: In that case I would close examine the combination _sending from Pi to somewhere through Zigbee_ and check the communication details.

Answer (score 0):

```
  serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
```

I see that the sending end isn’t using flow control. You definitely need to do that so you don’t overflow buffers on the XBee module. Without flow control, you’ll end up sending data that won’t get transmitted. My guess is that Real Term had flow control enabled, and that’s why your data arrived.

You should also enable it on the receiver, although it’s less likely you won’t be able to keep up with the data coming in.

I don’t know the details of the API on the receiving end, but it should be prepared for delays on received data. You could wait for a 1-2 second quiet period (while receiving and appending that data to your buffer) before considering the transfer “done” and saving the file.